# Automatically insert data from a MongoDB script file when the Java application is built

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, maven-3

I have a mongo script file fruitdata.js for inserting data to the mongo collection.I want to execute this script when we build the java application.

```
// Insert fruits into the "fruit" collection

use fruits;
db.fruit.insertMany([
{ name: "Apple", color: "Red"},
{ name: 
 "Banana",color:"Yellow" },
{ name: "Orange", color: 
"Orange" }
]);
```

The script file can be modified as required. could someone please suggest someways for making this possible. I have tried few solutions nothing is working. Thanks in advance.